# Deleting datacolumn after running db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, datacolumn

This is really frustrating...I'm working on a project with two other collaborators and every time I clone the respository and run `rake db:migrate` one column from the database disappears in the schema.  Why is this happening?

Comment: Is there a migration to remove that column?

Comment: No, but we actually can't find the migration that added the column to the database...? On any of our versions - is it possible this migration exists locally on one of their machines?

Comment: Yes it's possible that someone created that migration, but never committed it, but did commit the schema. The migration file could be in a git stash or on someone's branch.

Comment: Looks like someone deleted a migration locally on their machine and then committed...when anyone pulled and then ran db:migrate, the schema would update and delete the column.  Thanks!